# Calculating the Duration between two dates in R

Tags: r

I have two dates that are formatted as show below in Table 1: I'd like to calculate the duration in hours between the two dates. I tried using the lubridate package but it gave me an error about the dates being in a non-standard format.

```
  time.interval <- Begin %--% $End
  time.duration <- as.duration(time.interval)


   Begin                End
  1/12/2011 6:00 AM     1/12/2011 2:00 PM
  1/26/2011 5:00 PM     1/31/2011 8:00 AM
```

Comment: `lubridate` handles different date format. Usually dates in R are formatted like e.g. `"2011-12-01"`.  Check the package's [page](http://lubridate.tidyverse.org) for more information.

Comment: You do not need `lubridate`. Parse with `strptime()`, then use `difftime()`.

Comment: You can do: `difftime(as.POSIXlt(df$End, format = '%m/%d/%Y %I:%M %p'), as.POSIXlt(df$Begin, format = '%m/%d/%Y %I:%M %p'), units = 'mins')`